# How do I verify a GPG key with my commit email address on GitHub?

Tags: github, gnupg, gpg-signature

When I try to add a GPG key that uses my GitHub provided commit email address, it gives me an error that the email address is "Unverified." How should I fix this?

I followed the [guide on GitHub for generating a GPG key and adding it to your account](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-gpg-key), which says:

> Note: When asked to enter your email address, ensure that you enter the verified email address for your GitHub account. To keep your email address private, ***use your GitHub-provided no-reply email address***. For more information, see "Verifying your email address" and "Setting your commit email address."

See this screenshot that shows the error:

[image: Screenshot of GitHub SSH and GPG Keys settings page]

Comment: The GitHub documentation states if your account was created before 2017, your no-reply doesn't have an ID. But, this doesn't seem to be true since mine was created in 2013, and I'm also getting the `Unverified` issue. Or those emails cannot be used with GPG?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike when setting your commit email address, it is necessary to use the *full* noreply email address that GitHub provides. You can find it under the "Keep my email addresses private" section on the [GitHub email settings page](https://github.com/settings/emails). This email address should look something like:

> XXXXXXXX+USERNAME@users.noreply.github.com

Use this email address to generate your GPG key instead of simply using "USERNAME@users.noreply.github.com."

Answer (score 2):

My account was created in 2011 and even though my private e-mail address was shown in the new `ID+user@@users.noreply.github.com` format on the [Emails settings](https://github.com/settings/emails) page, further down under "Keep my email addresses private" it was shown in the old `user@users.noreply.github.com` format.

Credit to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1541215/240239) for suggesting to uncheck and check "Keep my email addresses private" again, which updated my private e-mail address to the new format and no longer appearing as unverified under [GPG keys](https://github.com/settings/keys).